# mongodb java driver hide id field in aggregation/projection operation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm performing an aggregation operation using the java mongodb driver, and I followed the example from the docs (pasted below). According to this, the `_id` field should be hidden. However, in my experience with my own code as well as the output of this example, the `_id` field doesn't hide even when setting the projection value to 0 (it works from the mongo shell). Does anyone know if this is a bug in the mongodb java driver? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
// create our pipeline operations, first with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("type", "airfare") );

// build the $projection operation
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("department", 1);
fields.put("amount", 1);
fields.put("_id", 0);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

// Now the $group operation
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$department");
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$amount"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

// run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( match, project, group );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _id field you are getting at the end is from the `$group` operator.  If you want to rename it back to department, add another `$project` to the end of the pipeline and translate _id to department.

Comment: I want to hide the _id field all together, which I thought putting _id as a 0 in projection should hide it

Comment: Look at the $group step - it's not getting the _id passed to it, but you are telling it to use $department as the _id (or key) that it's going to group by.  The original _id is *not* present in your result set.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to show _id at all in the resulting json. I want to group by department, but hide the _id field in the output.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?  A single field called "average"?  I'm guessing you want two fields, one called department and one called average.  So you need to $project `_id` to `department`

Comment: Right, I'd actually like it two fields department and average, but have it labeled as department, not _id in the json

Comment: Oh, that's what your original answer said, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: that's why you need to add another step to the pipeline that would be (in json) `{$project:{department:"$_id", average:1} }`

Comment: In this case, is the project actually doing anything? Wouldn't the output still be the same without it?

Comment: It renames the field _id which comes out of $group to department. Some projections are more sophisticated than others.  This one is very simple.